# Selenium webdriver,java, testng- Select date from a date picker(Date fitler) and click Apply button t

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to click on date filter, 2 calendars open to select TO date and FROM date and there calendars are in HTML table format i.e each date is in  tag. I want to choose specific date and click Apply button so that all the data get filtered based on the date range selected.I have tried by using both XPath and also by using code to trace though rows and columns. but it is not doing anything.

Comment: What is it doing? Is there something specific that you're stuck on? Examples would be good

Comment: I want to send specify year, month and date from selenium code that should get selected in the calendar(As date filter is read  only). for now I am just click on some number from calendar.So basically I want this calendar to work like it works when we use sendkeys, when date filter is not read only.